# No qualifying bean of type PlatformTransactionManager is defined, error happens only when it is not in-memory

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth

I have succesfully used the inMemory feature in order to create a HelloWorld Spring OAuth2. Now, I want to use MySql instead of inMemory. Bellow are the code I have tried so far.

I am getting the error mentioned in Title when I tried to reach it via PostMan with:

```
POST /myapp/oauth/token?grant_type=password&amp;username=myuser&amp;password=123456 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9080
Authorization: Basic Z3JlZW5jYXJkLXRydXN0ZWQtY2xpZW50OmdyZWVuY2FyZC1zZWNyZXQ=
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bcade5f5-fe47-3ea7-9c48-a054206f1c44
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

If I change the code bellow to use clients.inMemory().withClient it works. I have searched for an entire day what could be the reason and I read somewhere someone saying to use "@Transactional("transactionManagerName")" because it may be cause by duplicated jpa implementation (one in-memory and another the one pointed to mysql).

As far as I can see in my code below, I am not using in-memory feature at all. On top of that, I am not declaring @Transaction in anywhere as far as I can see.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciatted since it is my first time working with OAuth2 and I am seriously stuck.

datasource

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ConfigurationMySql {

    @Bean(name = "datasource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myappdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("myuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("mypwd");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurer

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }


    //

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }   
}
```

GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfigurer:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.jdbc(dataSource);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM+"/client");
    }


}
```

filter:

```java
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("doFilter");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        System.out.println("filterConfig");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroy");
    }

}
```

Tables created in order to replace ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer.inMemory:

```sql
drop table if exists oauth_client_details;

create table oauth_client_details (
client_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
resource_ids VARCHAR(255),
client_secret VARCHAR(255),
scope VARCHAR(255),
authorized_grant_types VARCHAR(255),
web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(255),
authorities VARCHAR(255),
access_token_validity INTEGER,
refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
additional_information VARCHAR(4096),
autoapprove VARCHAR(255)
);



drop table if exists oauth_client_token;
create table oauth_client_token (
token_id VARCHAR(255),
token LONG VARBINARY,
authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
user_name VARCHAR(255),
client_id VARCHAR(255)
);


drop table if exists oauth_access_token;
create table oauth_access_token (
token_id VARCHAR(255),
token LONG VARBINARY,
authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
user_name VARCHAR(255),
client_id VARCHAR(255),
authentication LONG VARBINARY,
refresh_token VARCHAR(255)
);


drop table if exists oauth_refresh_token;
create table oauth_refresh_token (
token_id VARCHAR(255),
token LONG VARBINARY,
authentication LONG VARBINARY
);


drop table if exists oauth_code;
create table oauth_code (
code VARCHAR(255), authentication LONG VARBINARY
);

drop table if exists oauth_approvals;
create table oauth_approvals (
userId VARCHAR(255),
clientId VARCHAR(255),
scope VARCHAR(255),
status VARCHAR(10),
expiresAt TIMESTAMP,
lastModifiedAt TIMESTAMP
);

drop table if exists ClientDetails;
create table ClientDetails (
appId VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
resourceIds VARCHAR(255),
appSecret VARCHAR(255),
scope VARCHAR(255),
grantTypes VARCHAR(255),
redirectUrl VARCHAR(255),
authorities VARCHAR(255),
access_token_validity INTEGER,
refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
additionalInformation VARCHAR(4096),
autoApproveScopes VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Tables created in order to replace AuthenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_role_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  role varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),
  UNIQUE KEY uni_username_role (role,username),
  KEY fk_username_idx (username),
  CONSTRAINT fk_username FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username));

CREATE  TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (username));
```

POM.xml:

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
  <springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.10.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
    <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurityoauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate >> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Where's the code to fetch data from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the PlatformTransactionManager Bean in ConfigurationMySql class.

```
@Bean public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() { return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource()); }
```