# Exception in Spring asynchronous job - InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, asynchronous, spring-batch

Scenario is, I have a spring boot application with a spring batch job. I'm trying to make the batch job asynchronous using `@EnableAsync` and `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and then assigning this taskExecutor to JobLauncher. After this change, job runs asynchronously, but I'm having an issue with persisting or updating database:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:489)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.abc.fin.rec.batch.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b55f85f1.updateRequestSummary(<generated>)
    at com.abc.fin.rec.batch.service.impl.BatchServiceImpl.updateRequestSummary(BatchServiceImpl.java:122)
    at com.abc.fin.rec.batch.service.impl.BatchServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b4c3b9f7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.abc.fin.rec.batch.service.impl.BatchServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9160b39.updateRequestSummary(<generated>)
    at com.abc.fin.rec.batch.cust.match.req.WriteToFileJobExecutionListener.beforeJob(WriteToFileJobExecutionListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeJobExecutionListener.beforeJob(CompositeJobExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:303)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.SpanContinuingTraceRunnable.run(SpanContinuingTraceRunnable.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3430)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1397)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1393)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.flush(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.flush(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.fin.rec.batch.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl.updateRequestSummary(CustomerDaoImpl.java:138)
        at com.abc.fin.rec.batch.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$333ee7df.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have tried using the DebugUtils mentioned here - http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2012/04/19/tips-for-debugging-springs-transactional-annotation/ and I have noticed from log, there is an active transaction before I call flush... but still this does not work.

Comment: I had this same exception and [moving from DataSourceTransactionManager to JpaTransactionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587328/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-transaction-is-in-progress/42591919#42591919) was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` the job method which takes care of database access logic.

Comment: It does not seem to work. Following is what I did as suggested, correct me, if missing anything:  

    @Bean
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Job gatherCustRequestData() throws Exception {
    final JobBuilder jb = jobBuilderFactory.get("gatherCustRequestData");
    jb.listener(gatherDataJobExecutionListener());
    SimpleJobBuilder sjb = jb.start(step1());
    sjb = sjb.next(step2());
  
    return sjb.build();
    }

Comment: This method doesn't seem to do any db write operation

Comment: Actually db write operation is in the gatherDataJobExecutionListener through DAO.

Answer (score 0):

`JobExecution#beforeJob` is not executed within the scope of a transaction managed by Spring Batch.  You may want to add the `@Transactional` to your `WriteToFileJobExecutionListener#beforeJob` method.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it results in same error. I have @Transactional annotation on the beforeJob method and also on the Dao class level.

Answer (score 0):

I already got this kind of problem in other context and there is only one efficient way to find out the source:
put break points in org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded
and in org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction
then try to understand why the transaction (supposed do be) created in later is not recognized by first one.

Comment: I was trying to debug these framework classes, but nothing that I could make. Can you provide more details? What was your fix? I was unable to open SessionImpl source to place breakpoint for some reason.

Comment: If you can't place breakpoints, it will be difficult to help
I needed to debug this kind of "tx problem" in some situations and none was exactly yours, one in JUNIT with a `@Transactional` hidden in a compound annotation used to configure the test (tx was already there when it should not...), the other one was a "self" call of the `@Transactional` method (also in a `@Async` context), thus not crossing the proxy boundary -> no Aspect applied, but this is not your situation since we see `TransactionInterceptor` in the stacktrace and another case was to debug REQUIRES_NEW not working in JUNIT